# Layout preview in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

When I create an Android blank app I can see the preview of my layout. But I now I created a Xamarin PCL app and here it doesn't show any preview of my XAML code. Is there any tool / view that can do this for my XAML code?

Comment: Welcome to the site. In order to receive help you need to provide [mcve]. Without it, it is impossible to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean but do you want a preview of how your XAML is going to loko in the application? If so you can use this:https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/

If it's not what you mean, could you try explaining it with screenshots perhaps?

Comment: Sorry this app doesn't allow me to send pics otherwise I will send u pics for better understanding

Comment: Did you try out the link? that's a tool you can use to preview your XAML code similar in the way that you were in your android blank app only.

Comment: Thank you so much,do I need to download it from internet or nuget :)

Comment: Normally it's already in your visual studios, you just have to activate by clicking in the menu ( of vs) on view - other windows - Xamarin forms previewer. If this has solved your problem, don't forget to mark my answer ;)

Comment: The previewer showing something went wrong.in details trying to load class........

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand, are you saying the previewer doesn't show up or that the code is invalid that u wrote?

Comment: Now it's opened thanks again and sorry to disturb you it was showing some kind of rendering error but now started

Comment: That's okay ;), for future post, I advise to give a bit more information and try to include screenshots. Also format your text a bit better ( for instance problem and afterwards what you want). Good luck in xamarin!